# Pandas: simple numeric subtract from one column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to simply subtract 2 from one column in a DataFrame. There are more columns in the df that need to remain unchanged.

The following has not effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
func = lambda x: x - 2

df["customer"].apply(func)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply()` function returns changed data frame, but it doesn't change your DF in place

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]:
   a  b  c
0  2  9  1
1  0  5  9
2  1  5  6
3  6  3  4
4  8  0  8

In [50]: df["a"].apply(func)
Out[50]:
0    0
1   -2
2   -1
3    4
4    6
Name: a, dtype: int64

In [51]: df
Out[51]:
   a  b  c
0  2  9  1
1  0  5  9
2  1  5  6
3  6  3  4
4  8  0  8
```

What you want is this: `df["customer"] -= 2`, which will work much faster, will looks better and it is more idiomatic

```
In [53]: df['a'] -= 2

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
   a  b  c
0  0  9  1
1 -2  5  9
2 -1  5  6
3  4  3  4
4  6  0  8
```